# A Mechanism for having different equals (physical equals and logical equals) on objects in Collection

Tags: java, list, collections, equals, comparator

Is there any Equalator mechanism like Comparator so I can have different equals for coparing lists?

**EDIT:** My goal is to differentiate between current list1.equals(list2) which checks if its a shallow copy or also a deep copy with all objects a.equals(b) and list1.identical(list2) which checks if its simply shallow copy with unmodified listing

All these lists are from the same model. Some are copies of themselves so they hold the pointer to same objects, and others are deep copies so hierarchy is totally replicated, because they have updates in content, not just in structure.

I find myself oftenly makin list1.equals(list2) but I need a mechanism for telling if both are  TOTAL copies (same objects in same order for collections) or sometimes if they are LOGICAL copies (through my own implemented logic equals), so list would call equals and objects should implement something more than a==b.

My problem is there is no Equalator interface, and if I override objects equals to I loose the capability of comparing by TOTAL EQUAL (a==b)

For example, this would be nice;

```
Collections.equal(l1,l2,new Equalator(){
    @Override public boolean equals(Obj1,Obj2){
          //Default lists comparison plus commparison of objects based on
          return (obj1.propertyX() == obj2.propertyX());
    }
});
```

and still I could do list1.equals(list2) so they use default equals (obj1==obj2) and this would be only true if contained objects are exactly the same.

First operation is useful for checking if list (which could be an updated list with totally recreated objects from the model) is still equals to the old list.

Second operation is useful for checking if list (which was a shallow copy of the old current version of data model), it does not contain any transcendent change from moving it around inside the code when it was the udpdated version.

**EDIT:** A very good example would be having a list of Point(x,y). We should be able to know if both list are equal because they are exactly same set of points or equal because the points they contain are equal in a logical way. If we could implement both phyEqual and logEqual to object, and have both methods in any object so list.phyEqual(list2) or list1.logEqual(list2)

Comment: You've got plenty of context, but what's your actual *question* here?

Comment: First line. Then I define my problem. Sorry, I started with 'isn´t there' instead of 'is there' and I think that is why its confusing

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't really come across clearly, at least to me.  If this doesn't answer it properly, could you re-word a little bit?

Within a given Collection concrete type, most equals implementations already do what you hint at.
For instance:

```
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this)
            return true;
```

In this case, something like this might make sense.
You can easily override this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o.getPrimaryKey() == this.getPrimaryKey()) 
            return true;
        return super().equals(o);
```

[test for nulls should be added]
If you are creating standard collections, you can even anonymously override the equals method during construction.

If this doesn't do what you want, you could extend Collections yourself and override any of the methods there to do a similar thing.

Does that help?

Comment: List at least, has an equal which looks both lists have same size, same elements and same order. The problem is it uses equal for telling if both objects are the same, so it means that without an equalator interface, I have to change whole framework in order to have an additional chain of equalities. I can implement equals in my objects as logical or physial equal, but then I cannnot swith to the other type

Comment: There are very few real-world cases in which there's more than one definition of equals that is actually of use to anyone.

Comment: List. list.equals(list2) if both have same size, elements, and order of them (taking into account elements are equals if they satisfy a.equals(b)). But list.equals2(list2) could mean both have same size, elements and order (taking into account 2 obj are equals if a==b). Of course, assuming we can not assure a.equals(b) is not overridn so does not go further than a==b

Answer (score 2):

A late answer, but maybe it will be useful for someone...

The Guava [Equivalence](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) class is the same for equivalence as Comparator for comparing. You would need to write your own method for comparing the lists (there is no support in Guava for that), but then you could call this method with various equivalence-definitions.

Or you can roll your own interface:

```
interface Equalator<T> {
    boolean equals(T o1, T o2);
}
```

Again, you need to write your (trivial) method

```
boolean <T> listEquals(List<T> list1, List<T> list2, Equalator<T> equalator) {
    ...  
}
```

...but then you can reuse it with different ListEqualator implementations.