# Implementing an "absolute equals" method (called same() or identical()) to Object. Good idea?

Tags: java, object, collections, equals, comparable

Would this be a good idea? How can it be solved, if not, nowadays?

I think it would be interesting adding an

```
final boolean identical(Obj obj){
   return (this==obj);
}
```

so we had an improved equals (logical equals)

```
boolean equals (Obj obj){
   return identical(obj); // by default, but its overrideable
}
```

This question arised from the need in this other question ([A Mechanism for having different equals (physical equals and logical equals) on objects in Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758220/a-mechanism-for-having-different-equals-physical-equals-and-logical-equals-on)) of having a way to compare a list of identical pointers to a list of equally objects. With that idea we could add to the Collection interface:

```
 coll.equals(coll2)
 coll.identical(coll2)
 coll.identicalElem(coll2){
      //current equals implementation of collections but calling identical to compare objects
 }
```

What do you think?

Comment: What is the difference between your method and `==`?

Comment: If you want to compare identities rather than "equality", just don't override `equals()` in your own objects...

Comment: This is a case of reinventing the wheel.  Primarily (in my opinion) this happens when someone finds themselves to be more intelligent than all computer scientists before them.

Comment: Ok, you are right, IMHO, as long as I write the method as final. But it can be clear see in case of lists. If list.equals currently checks any object equality inside of it, list.identity could check any object identity inside of it.

Comment: I did not know everyone would find this question so stupid and also pedantic just because I think I could improve something (thats why I ask for feedback, if I was sure, and I am not beause I am a begginer, I had not put it here in SO). But I will put myself the third close vote. Thank you all.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: It's generally useful to regard object instances whose state matches now but might not match in future as distinct; while regarding objects whose state will match now and forever as identical.  I could see some definite usefulness for having an equals/hashcode pair which would test for transitory equivalence and one which would test for permanent equivalence, especially if the type system could distinguish between e.g. an `int[]` encapsulating an unshared array that may change, one encapsulating the content of a sharable array that will never change, or...

Comment: ...one that identifies a shared array which encapsulates shared state; and if generic collections could know what kind of reference they held.  Often, code which holds a collection will know whether the things in the collection may ever be exposed to code that could modify them, a distinction which should affect the equivalence reported by those items, but with only one standard form of equivalence defined, there's no standard way for the collection owner to indicate which form of equivalence the collection should look for in its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `equals()` implementation you posted is already the one in `java.lang.Object`. There's no real point in overriding it with the same implementation.

Regarding your 3 methods to add to the collection interface:

`coll.equals(coll2)`: this one is already in the Collection interface.

`coll.identical(coll2)`: equivalent to `coll == coll2`, but less readable. I don't see the point of such a method.

`coll.identicalElem(coll2)`: this method indeed doesn't exist, but I've never had the need for such a method, so I think it should not clutter the API of Collection. You could use Guava's [Equivalence](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) to do that:

```
Equivalence.identity().pairWise().equivalent(coll1, coll2);
```

Comment: The third one is the clue why i am asking this question. How an I tell if a collection is a shallow copy or a deep copy with all objects obj1.equals(obj2)? Ill try your method!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're aware of this, but there already is IdentityHashMap in the standard Java API. Also, you can generate objects' hashcodes with System.identityHashCode.

Answer (score 0):

The existing "equals" method on object already does this - right?

Here is the code:

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj);
    }
```

So if you provide an implementation for 'equals' it executes that, if not (then by default), it uses "=="'s

Comment: Yes but it can be overriden so you can never make sure two obejcts are equals IF and ONLY IF they are identical (or ==). make two lists compare between them. They an be true even if they are not the same instance it seems.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea because `equals(Object)` is testing if two instances of a class are equal, not if they represent the same instance (i.e. their pointers are equal).

If you implement that "improved" equals method, you will wind up with things like:
`new Rectangle(1, 2).equals(new Rectangle(1, 2))` returning false, which would be absurd.

In addition, there is a ton of code out there that relies on the current definition of the `equals` method (for example HashMaps use it to resolve hashcode conflicts for objects that aren't the same). Things would blow up all over the place for no particular reason.

The `identical` method you propose also doesn't add any value over the existing `==` operator.

In my opinion, override the `equals` method for your objects where it makes sense (although I even question that), but you would definitely not want to suggest changing it at the top level and its default behavior for all objects.

Comment: The commenters are right, identical() would mean ==. We can discuss the utility of such an alias, but the point is that any object would have an identical method plus an equals one defaulting to identical. That means new Rectangle(1,2).equals(new Rectangle(1,2)) should be always true, but new Rectangle(1,2).identical(new Rectangle(1,2)) always false. My problem is that I think equals is used for both meanings of equality nowadays and I always have problems with it.

Comment: It would be useful to have a definition of equivalence separate from equality or reference equality, such that two things are equivalent *if they are equal and there is no way that they could be mutated to become unequal*.  Had `Object` supported separate tests for equality and equivalence, collections could have done so as well (two collections are equal if they contain equal items; they are equivalent if they can be guaranteed to always contain equivalent items).