# I want to extend ArrayList to implement but cannnot access to elementData private var

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, overriding, extend

I would like to know how can I override `indexOf()` method in a subclass of `ArrayList`. I need to use the same accessing that super to the **private transient `elementData`** var.

How can I solve my design?

**EDIT:** Could it be a valid solution changing the call to elementData[i] to a similar this.get(i) (which is actually allowed?). Would it corrupt or break the logic someway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't, basically. Use *composition* instead, if you want to create a collection which behaves in a way which isn't the same as `ArrayList`. The private details of `ArrayList` are private for good reason; they're implementation details which could change between versions, and your code shouldn't care about them.

(It's *possible* that extending `ArrayList` is actually a valid approach, but unlikely IMO. You haven't said what you're really trying to achieve, just what's stopping you from achieving it. If you could tell us more about the big picture, we're more likely to be able to help.)

Comment: I am doing a wrapper for my Arraylist so I can use a different equal-compare logic as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758220/a-mechanism-for-having-different-equals-physical-equals-and-logical-equals-on. But I dont want to implement the 700 hundred methods of interface List.

Comment: @user1352530 there are far fewer than 700 methods in `List`. Most IDEs will create the stub methods for you.

Comment: Could it be a valid solution changing the call to elementData[i] to a similar this.get(i) (which is actually allowed?). Would it corrupt or break the logic someway?

Comment: Absolutely, yes.  Or, even better -- don't violate the `List` contract by using a different `equals()` logic; instead write a method that takes a `List` and an `Object` and finds the index of that object according to your different logic.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a container, which provides the same methods as an ArrayList and has a field of type ArrayList (for the data storage). Then you add all ArrayList methods to your container class, which execute the corresponding method on the ArrayList (field) except those you want to override.

Comment: And the answer on the comment can be applied here too

Comment: What you described is the composition pattern.

Comment: Uh didn't see the comments -.-

Comment: No worry, its a good answer, but this communnity is faster than light! Thanks for helping!